# Fatal error: Class 'Walker_Nav_Primary' not found

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to change the markup for the nav on my site and I am pretty new to developing wordpress, but I am having issues getting it to display my Walker class. I am attempting to reconfigure the 2017 theme that comes with Wordpress. But I keep getting this error that says "Fatal error: Class 'Walker_Nav_Primary' not found in /wp-content/themes/Vibe/header.php on line 56" This is what the class looks like:

```
<?php
  class Walker_Nav_Primary extends Walker_Nav_menu {

    function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ){ //ul
        $indent = str_repeat("\t",$depth);
        $submenu = ($depth > 0) ? ' sub-menu' : '';
        $output .= "\n$indent<ul class=\"dropdown-menu$submenu depth_$depth\">\n";
    }
    /*  
    function start_el( ){ //li a span
    }
    function end_el(){ // closing li a span
    }

    function end_lvl(){ // closing ul

    }
    */
     }
```

And the portion of my header file where I am calling it:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array(
    'theme_location' => 'top',
    'menu_id'        => 'primary-menu',
    'menu_class'        => 'head-menu',
    'walker'            =>  new Walker_Nav_Primary(),
) ); ?>
```

EDIT:

```
// This theme uses wp_nav_menu() in two locations.
register_nav_menus( array(
    'top'    => __( 'Top Menu', 'twentyseventeen' ),
    'social' => __( 'Social Links Menu', 'twentyseventeen' ),
) );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put his in your functions.php file

```
// Register Custom Navigation Walker
require_once get_template_directory() . '/walker-fie-name.php';
```

Try this and reply if any issue.

In your case, it should be

```
require_once get_template_directory() . '/inc/walker.php';
```

Update you walker.php file with this code

```
<?php
if ( ! class_exists( 'Walker_Nav_Primary' ) ) {
  class Walker_Nav_Primary extends Walker_Nav_menu {

    public function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ){ //ul
        $indent = str_repeat("\t",$depth);
        $submenu = ($depth > 0) ? ' sub-menu' : '';
        $output .= "\n$indent<ul class=\"dropdown-menu$submenu depth_$depth\">\n";
    }
}
```

Put in function.php file at very top

Replace

```
require_once get_template_directory() . '/inc/walker.php';
```

With this code.

```
if ( ! file_exists( get_template_directory() . '/inc/walker.php' ) ) {
    // file does not exist... return an empty page with msg not found
    wp_die('Not found');
} else {
    // file exists... require it.
    require_once get_template_directory() . '/inc/walker.php';
}
```

Comment: It crashed the site: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in /home3/wwahidi5102/p2site.wafiwahidi.com/wp-content/themes/Vibe/functions.php on line 61. But it's not live so I am not worried.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting function (T_FUNCTION) in /home3/wwahidi5102/p2site.wafiwahidi.com/wp-content/themes/Vibe/inc/walker.php on line 60

Comment: I'm using an example walker from a tutorial, I don't know if it could be the walker.php

Comment: it should be at the top of the file and make sure the path is correct.

Comment: Yeah it's correct and at the top and it still gives me that same error. Could it have to do with this snippet: 
 // This theme uses wp_nav_menu() in two locations.
 register_nav_menus( array(
  'top'    => __( 'Top Menu', 'twentyseventeen' ),
  'social' => __( 'Social Links Menu', 'twentyseventeen' ),
 ) );
This is what is at line 60

Comment: Put that code snippet on the question it is hard to understand.

Comment: For sure, it is added to the question.

Comment: There something wrong on line number 59 or 60 either you close the php tag or didn't open it. Or you added a '<' extra. Also, make sure the code inside the walker is correct.

Comment: There is no character there. There must be something else with the theme

Comment: Added an error handler in my update. Reply the output that you get.

Comment: Ok so the site is not broken, however I don't the function actually worked. Here is the site if you want to verify http://p2site.philippesphotography.com

Comment: Replace the var to this `$output = "test";` if the test is printed they you are good to go.

Comment: Nevermind, it works! My stupid self forgot I have taken the "walker" attribute out of the "wp_nav_menu()". It looks messed up but I'm assuming that is because I haven't finished the walker class. Does that sound right?

Comment: Ya you need to output something to  see changes happening.

Comment: Ok so maybe this is quite there. It removes the sub menus and when I set $output = "test"; it didn't output "test".

Comment: You are doing something wrong in your code. But the walker file is imported in properly so your issue is resolved.

Comment: You can start a new thead so people who have more idea than me in walkers can help you. If possible paste the link here I will try to help you.

Comment: Ok cool, as long as it is imported properly now I'm also assuming I'll have to set the end_lvl, start_el, end_el as public functions as well?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe require works  , in header php file

```
require_once('xxx/xxx/Walker_Nav_Primary.php');
```

Comment: @leekun No it still doesn't work. I tried that earlier and it seemed to ignore the walker class.

Comment: @Rajendran Where should I put it? The directory of the walker.php file is /wp-content/themes/Vibe/inc/walker.php. How do I get it to reference the file?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change this code!

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array(
'theme_location' => 'top',
'menu_id'        => 'primary-menu',
'menu_class'        => 'head-menu',
'walker'            =>  new Walker_Nav_Primary(),) ); ?>
```

to this:

```
    <?php 
$walker = new Walker_Nav_Primary;
wp_nav_menu( array(
    'theme_location' => 'top',
    'menu_id'        => 'primary-menu',
    'menu_class'        => 'head-menu',
    'walker'            =>  $walker,) ); ?>
```

Comment: You are doing the same thing.